# API with multiple credientials for the same API

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a question about external API connections with multiple connections to the same api.

SITUATION: I have a Laravel app that must connect to an external API. So far it’s not that difficult, there is even a wrapper on GitHub that I can use (github.com/homedesignshops/laravel-bol-com-retailer). But here’s the catch. I have multiple accounts on this platform so I need multiple connections. I can rewrite the main class so the wrapper has 3 connections in one singleton that I can call and by specifying a key I can call a single connection. This feels a bit hacky and I think there is a better way, maybe by using the service container. If the service container is the way to go, then please point me in the right direction, because I haven’t used that a lot.

WHAT I HAVE DONE: I have rewritten the class so it authenticates with multiple accounts. But as explained this feels overly complex.

Comment: Writing a proxy class, which will internally use 3 different instances of the library connector seems like a decent solution. And how do you think service container could be helpful here?